# Android NavigationView: How do I handle / disable selection of the header layout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I have a simple navigation drawer layout setup. I'm using the design support library so I have one a navigation view that slides in above the support library's toolbar. However, the header layout is responding to taps in the UI. I'm getting that ripple effect appearing behind the header layout when I tap it. How can I do either of the following:

1. Disable the tap interaction all together? (so no ripple effect occurs)
2. Respond to the tap interaction.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the same issue. This component uses a ListView internally (called menuView below), and unfortunately there is no option to disable the header selection because it's hard-coded:

```
this.mHeader = (LinearLayout)this.mLayoutInflater.inflate(layout.design_navigation_item_header, this.mMenuView, false);
this.mMenuView.addHeaderView(this.mHeader);
this.mMenuView.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);
this.mMenuView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Adding that to the fact that the NavigationView also has an icons coloring bug (in version 22.2.0), I would suggest to not use it for the moment.

Comment: What is the coloring bug you're describing?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a workaround for the issue:

```
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_nav, mNavigationView, false);
mNavigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);

//Use this if you don't want the click listener, 
//be sure to use the appropriate background color 
//((ViewGroup) headerView.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_material_light);

//If you want your header to respond to clicks, this should suffice
headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Open to your implementation
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the layout resource "design_navigation_item_header" and add  background color and then you will not see the ripple.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navigation_separator_vertical_padding"/>
```

If you wanted to respond to the click you could look up the view by id and add an OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Taking hints from [razzledazzle's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490324/2524470), simply consuming the onClick works

```
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header_view, menuItemsNavigationView, false);

headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Consume input from header view. This disables the ripple effect
    }
});

menuItemsNavigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this in my own app. A NavigationView is a ScrimInsetsFrameLayout wrapped around a ListView and it explicitly ignores (throws out) clicks on the first item of the list, which is the header.

However, you can retrieve them yourself by wrapping the NavigationView’s onItemClickListener with your own:

```
    ListView menuList = (ListView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
    final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener nativeListener = menuList.getOnItemClickListener();
    menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                onUserClicked(prefs.getUser());
            }
            nativeListener.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        }
    });
```

Normally I don’t endorse this kind of relying on the internals of Android widgets, but in this case it’s the support library, which is packaged and shipped with your app. It’s probably better to build your own custom navigation view in the long run, but sometimes you need a quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions on this page worked for me, and probably with good reason. As the accepted answer by BladeCoder states, the listener is hard-coded into the NavigationDrawer ListView, and the header view is the 0th item of the ListView's Adapter. Simply overriding the onClickListener for the inflated header view won't work if you want to actually disable it, as you need to reference the onClickListener for the ListView's Adapter item instead of just the inflated view.

The below solution works for me to disallow clicking/tapping the header view, but it does not disable focusability (with a d-pad or keyboard for example). I can't seem to figure out how just yet.

```
    //get the listview within the navigation drawer (0th child)
    ListView menuList = (ListView) mNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

    //get the header view (0th item in listview adapter)
    final View headerView = menuList.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);

    if (headerView != null) {
        headerView.setEnabled(false); //doesn't work, should
        headerView.setFocusable(false); //doesn't work, should
        headerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); //doesn't work, should
        headerView.setClickable(false); //doesn't work, should
        headerView.setOnClickListener(null); //WORKS! works to disallow clicking! is still focusable via keyboard
    }
```